# unexpexted statistics in execution plan

Tags: sql-server-2008

Querying a view in mssql database (say db2) from another mssql database (say db1) executes very slowly (about 2 minutes).  db1 and db2 reside in same sqlserver instance.  View in db2 is used to do queries upon.  View can't be indexed due to certain reasons.
It seems that when indexes are used in a query plan, actual number of rows and expected number of rows differ significantly.

But executing similar query from within db2 runs ok - about 5 seconds.  Actual and expected number of rows are similar.

Rebuilding indexes doesn't seem to reflect changes in execution plan (fro quering db2 from db1).

So, my question is - why stats are so different?  May be statistics of db2 isn't visible to query optimizer when running from db1?

Comment: Are you querying the other database through a linked server or just a cross database query on the same instance? There are issues with [linked servers](http://www.benjaminnevarez.com/2011/05/optimizer-statistics-on-linked-servers/) that have recently [been mitigated](http://www.benjaminnevarez.com/2013/02/dbcc-show_statistics-works-with-select-permission/) in SQL Server 2012 SP

Comment: I am querying via public view defined in second database (same sqlserver instance).  It can't be indexed because it has a function inside.

Comment: Try executing `sp_refreshview` and see if it helps.

Comment: Please post the actual execution plans (XML) for both good and bad versions. See [How do I provide an execution plan to someone for analysis?](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/a/797) for more about this.